# CSS full page height content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to build a website with a full height whatever the user's screen. Scroll is impossible, everything is shown in the page.
I tried something like :

```
<body>
  <div class="header">
    test
  </div>
  <div class="central">
    test
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    test
  </div>
</body>

html,body{
  height:100%;
}
.header,.footer{
    height: 20%;
  background-color:blue;
}
.central{
    min-height:60%;
  background-color:red;
}
```

It works in my screen with a big resolution but not in my 15", page is scrollable. If body is limited to 100%, why all the elements aren't in the page?
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/h023v0uw/)

Thanks.

Comment: You need to reset CSS before applying your own CSS, because there's a browser applied default margin to `body`. In this case you could get away with applying `margin:0;` to `body`, but it's better to use a general CSS reset such as http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: @leroydev the `body` tag has `margin`, not `padding` and I disagree strongly with *it being better to use a general reset* since some defaults are actually *not bad* and without for instance `padding` on a `ul` (due to the reset) you won't see the bullets in front of the items etc...

Comment: Check this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space?rq=1)

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand haha sorry, fixed it, friday afternoons hehe..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the body has built-in `margin`.

Just remove it.

A normal [CSS Reset](http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/) would generally have this as standard.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  /* see? */
}
.header,
.footer {
  height: 20%;
  background-color: blue;
}
.central {
  min-height: 60%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    test
  </div>
  <div class="central">
    test
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    test
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. I followed your link and did a CSS reset

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because the body has margins. Try :

```
html,body { 
  height:100%; 
  min-height:100%; 
  max-height:100%; 
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set min height to html tag and remove default margin, padding to body tag

```
html{  
    min-height:100%;
}

body{

    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    min-height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}
```

Comment: Please add details to your answer so that OP and future readers can understand why this is the answer to the question